# How to Convert SQL Query to Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

MY SQL Query:
`` SELECT * ,COUNT(posts_id) as `view `FROM `post_view` JOIN posts ON post_view.posts_id = posts.id 
GROUP BY
posts_id ``
My Eloquent Laravel:

```
$this->model->Join('posts','post_view.posts_id', '=', 'posts.id')
          ->selectRaw('*, count(posts_id) as view')
          ->groupBy('posts_id')
          ->get();
```

Error when Get by Postman:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'databasePost.post_view.id' isn't in GROUP BY
        (SQL: select *, count(posts_id) as view from `post_view` inner join `posts` on `post_view`.`posts_id` =
        `posts`.`id` group by `posts_id`)
```

Comment: what have you tried ? and what variable you set in related model ?

Comment: tou have to set model for that and then you can use that model class for laravel eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because `group by` requiring all columns, is the speed of the query.

I think you are using a MySQL server with version 5.7.5+.
Check this out: [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

### Method 1:

Use `ANY_VALUE` to the column or disable mysql mode:`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.`

```php
->selectRaw('ANY_VALUE(post_view.id), ... count(posts_id) as view')
          ->groupBy('posts_id')
```

PS: `post_view.id` and `posts.id` both named `id`, select them all out that one of them will be covered.

### Method 2:

edit your applications's database config file `config/database.php`

In mysql array, set `strict => false` to disable MySQL's strict mode:

```php
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            ...
            'strict' => false,
        ],
```

Comment: Temporarily I used the method 2.

Comment: @ltt88 Using either of these methods may hide some rows. Make sure you know what you're doing when using them